# How to take a screenshot of a particular QWidget in a tab in QT and post it in another tab?

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot, qwidget

I have a tab that is to display data that is to be prepared for a report. Kind of like a preview. What I want is to take a screenshot of graph generated in another tab.

Kind of similar to scanning an image. So the initial tab generates 3 graphs under each other that fit in the screen. I basically want the screen shots of the graphs to post them along with the data in the second tab.

[image]

[image]

The second image is where I want the content of the first image to be posted. How do I go on about that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve but you might want to look at [`QWidget::render`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#render).

Comment: Let me clarify, I basically want to take a screenshot of the graphs in the tab shown in the first image and display this screenshot in the tab shown in the second image in the place highlighted in red